# Help with pagination

Tags: sql-server, pagination, php-5.3

I have created pagination and it is currently working, but the only issue is if I have thousands and thousands of results... the display would be:

[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18] and so on.

I just want the display the page to display to look similar to this:

previous [1][2][3][4][5]... next

previous ...[5][6][7][8][9][10]...next

Can anyone give advice or supply some example code that would give me a result like above? If anything is at all unclear please let me know!

Cheers,

Neil

The code that I am currently using is below:

```
<?php
/*data base connection */

include "datebase connection";

/* SQL query */

$tsql = ("  SELECT   TOP 100  tie_parent_id, CAST(geo_post AS varchar(6)) + '.' + CAST(geo_sample AS varchar(6)) AS Mile, gps_lat, gps_long, rotten, split, wheel_cut, broken, quality
FROM  database
");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static'));
if( $stmt === false)
{
     echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* DETERMINING THE NUMBER OF ROWS (AND PAGES) */

// Set the number of rows to be returned on a page. 
$rowsPerPage = 10;

// Get the total number of rows returned by the query.  
$rowsReturned = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);


if($rowsReturned === false) 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
elseif($rowsReturned == 0) 
{ 
    echo "No rows returned."; 
    exit(); 
} 
else 
{     
    /* Calculate number of pages. */ 
    $numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage); 
}


/* FUNCTION FOR PAGING */



function getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage ) 
{ 
    $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage; 
    $rows = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, 
                                    SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC, 
                                    SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, 
                                    $offset + $i) 
           && $i < $rowsPerPage) 
    { 
        array_push($rows, $row); 
        $i++; 
    } 
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC,SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $offset -1);
    return $rows; 
}


// Display the selected page of data. 
echo "<table width='800' border='0'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Tie ID</th> <th>Mile/Yard</th> <th>GPS Lat</th><th>GPS Long</th><th>Rotten</th><th>Split</th><th>WheelCut</th> <th>Broken</th><th>Quality</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
$pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? $_GET['pageNum'] : 1; 
$page = getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage);


$color1 = "#ffffff"; 
$color2 = "#edf5fa"; 
$row_count = "0";



while($row_count<10 ) {

$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
$tie_parent_id = $row["tie_parent_id"];
$geo_post = $row["Mile"];
$lat =$row["gps_lat"];
$long =$row["gps_long"];
$rotten =$row["rotten"];
$split =$row["split"];
$wheelcut =$row["wheel_cut"];
$broken =$row["broken"];
$quality =$row["quality"];

$row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2; 


?>

<tr> 

<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["tie_parent_id"]; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["Mile"];?> </td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["gps_lat"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["gps_long"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["rotten"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["split"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["wheel_cut"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["broken"];?></td>
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color ?>">
<?php echo $row["quality"];?></td>
</td></tr>


<?php
    $row_count++; 
}
?>


<?php
/* PREVIOUS PAGE NAVIGATION TOP OF PAGE */

// Display Previous Page link if applicable. 
if($pageNum > 1) 
{ 
    $prevPageLink = "?pageNum=".($pageNum - 1); 
    echo "<a href='$prevPageLink'>Previous Page</a>&nbsp"; 
}

/*DISPLAYING LINKS TO PAGES TOP OF PAGE*/
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)  
{  
    $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";  
    print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");  
}

/* NEXT PAGE NAVIGATION TOP OF PAGE */


// Display Next Page link if applicable. 
if($pageNum < $numOfPages) 
{ 
    $nextPageLink = "?pageNum=".($pageNum + 1); 
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='$nextPageLink'>Next Page</a>"; 
}
?>
</form>
<?php

/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The change is actually not too crazy - you have most of it. Your algorithm needs to change just a little bit for the display of the pages - so instead of running your loop like you have:

```
/*DISPLAYING LINKS TO PAGES TOP OF PAGE*/
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)  
{      
     $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";      
     print("$i  ");  
}
```

You need to start at the current page number that you are on...

```
/*first check to make sure the number of pages don't exceed maximum*/
$totalPagesToLoop = $pageNum + $numOfPages;
if($totalPagesToLoop > ceiling(total number of pages required to show all the records ([number of total rows]/[number of rows to show per page])
{
     $totalPagesToLoop = ceiling(total number of pages required to show all the records ([number of total rows]/[number of rows to show per page]);
}



/*DISPLAYING LINKS TO PAGES TOP OF PAGE*/
for($i = $pageNum; $i<=$totalPagesToLoop; $i++)  
{      
     $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";      
     print("$i  ");  
}
```

But - thats not all, you will now have to code the special 'previous' and 'next' buttons (you decide how many to increment when you click on that - google increments by 1, until it reaches 20, and then just shows 20 at a time, moving one by one. You'll have to test your  variable to decide whether to show the 'previous' or 'next' button at all...

Comment: Thank you for your reply M.R! Your code was very useful! I managed to resolve the issue with something slightly different... Cheers, Neil

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by using the below code:

```
for($i = $pageNum; $i<=$numOfPages&&$pagesadded<=9; $i++)  
{  
    $pagesadded+=1;
    $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";  
    print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");  
}
```

It displays 10 pages at a time.

Cheers,

Neil